# Decimals in DB2

Tags: db2

I use iNavigator to query Data from DB2. During calculations, is there a possibility to get the output in the following format? Currently the output is exported to excel and decimals are assigned.

1235*3.24 = **4,001.40**

Comment: ...do you mean output the actual formula used, as opposed to (just) the result?

Comment: _where_ do you want the format to be applied?  Inside Excel?  iNavigator?

Comment: Inside iNavigator. I need the results to be in the above format. I use DECIMAL(transaction_amount * conversion_rate,12,2) AS ACTUAL_AMOUNT but it doesn't give the results in the above format.

Comment: There's a way to set the decimal/thousands separator, and other formatting, as if it were a regular terminal session, but I can't remember where/how, and can't find a manual.  If you figure it out you can answer your own question.

Comment: Will it be in iNavigator settings?

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve the issue; formatting adds commas:

**`VARCHAR_FORMAT( SUM(BAL_BOOK_AMT), '999,999,999,999.99') AS SUM`**